# Is "English" or "en" the preferred .lproj folder name now?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, macos, localization

In Apple's documentation and example code, I see lproj folders both named with the name of the language, such as "English", and with an ISO 639 code, such as "en".

What is the definitive naming requirement? I have not been able to find it.

If there isn't one, what are the advantages and disadvantages of each type of name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The ISO 639 code is the preferred name.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html)

Comment: The link is dead, anyone who comes here this might work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Answer (score 2):

See also: [Using “en” instead of “English” for your Xcode project’s development region](http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=224), which tells you how to hack your Xcode project so that using en is less of a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Now of course after some more Googling I do find the definitive guide:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002144

"English" is old. Don't use it. These are still recognized, however. Also I note that Xcode still shows these when you create a new localization. Filed as rdar://problem/7219844

"en" or "eng" is current. Do use it.

Comment: Since @Peter (your accepted answer) already linked to this, it would be "cleaner" to add your commentary as a comment to his answer. Thanks for filing a Radar and including the number. :-)

Comment: BTW, rdar://7219844 is a duplicate of rdar://3160993, originated in 2003. Mentioning one or both numbers in any related bugs will simplify triage.